# vector storing lambdas -- CLANG vs the other two

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

Here is the code.

```
// .
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#define CAT_(a, b) a##b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)
#define REG(x) inline auto CAT(unused_name_, __LINE__ ) =      tu_register(x)
#define LNE printf("%d", __LINE__ )

typedef void (*fp_required)( ) ;
using fvec_type = std::vector< fp_required > ;

static fvec_type fvec{};

inline bool tu_register( fp_required const & fp ){
        printf("\nRegistered: %p" , fp ) ;
        fvec.push_back( fp ) ;
    return true ;
 }

REG([]{ LNE; }) ; // 3 stateless lambdas
REG([]{ LNE; }) ;
REG([]{ LNE; }) ;

int main()
{
printf("\n\nRegistered %lu lambdas. %s\n", fvec.size(), (fvec.size() > 0 ? "Now calling them": ""));
for ( auto & fun : fvec ) {
   printf("\nCalling lambda %p , rezult: " , fun);
   fun() ;
}
  return 0;
}
```

CLANG compiles with no warnings, but places exactly nothing  in the vector?

https://wandbox.org/permlink/nkYjgqvr5QOprKEn

G++ compiles with no warnings, and works as expected.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/a6HB6xzavE8FOyOi

MSVC (the latest VS2019, all up to date) too, compiles and works no problems.

Who is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code *should* work, and in Clang 8.0.0, it does.  Looks like it was broken after that, and doesn't work in 9.0.0 nor 10.0.0 on Wandbox.

Comment: @ John Zwinck , many thanks, I am bound to clang 8.0.1 as it is delivered by VS2019. Spent Saturday morning on this one :(

Comment: @ John Zwinck,   https://wandbox.org/permlink/fYDiQKJDEpcKCI4H -- using CLANG 8.0.0 works ok. From 8.0.1 up to 11 it does not. How do we obtain CLANG 11?

Comment: @ChefGladiator: I'm sorry I misspoke earlier, I am also using Clang 8.0.0.  Clang 11 isn't released yet, I was misled by the "Apple clang version 11.0.0" version string on my Mac, but in fact "Apple clang version 11.0.0" means Clang 8.0.0 (how stupid is that?), according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions .  So in fact you'll need to downgrade your Clang to 8.0.0 and/or report a bug to Clang.

Comment: @ John Zwinck, ah clear now ... I got also mightily confused with Apple CLANG 11 situation .. godbolt afficionados will be very clear what is the exact problem, but we need solution on the code level ,,, I have tried few other containers, but it is very difficult when there are absolutely no warnings, it seems something just gets "optimized away" to zero bytes ....